# Custom animations in Compass?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, css-animations

I am wondering how can i transle this to compass mixins

```
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 0px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
.item:hover{
    -webkit-animation-name: shake;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

I really [can't find much](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transform/) help about this in their docs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use the master branch (0.13.alpha) of compass, or the [compass-animation](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation) plugin, you can use existing animation mixins. Compass 0.12 already has mixins for transforms as well. All together it would look like this:

```
@include keyframes(shake) {
    0% { @include transform(translate(2px, 0px) rotate(0deg)); }
    10% { @include transform(translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-1deg)); }
    20% { @include transform(translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg)); }
    30% { @include transform(translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg)); }
    40% { @include transform(translate(1px, 0px) rotate(1deg)); }
    50% { @include transform(translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-1deg)); }
    60% { @include transform(translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(0deg)); }
    70% { @include transform(translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg)); }
    80% { @include transform(translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg)); }
    90% { @include transform(translate(2px, 0px) rotate(0deg)); }
    100% { @include transform(translate(1px, 0px) rotate(-1deg)); }
}
.item:hover{
    @include animation(shake 0.8s infinite linear);
    @include transform-origin(50% 50%);
}
```

That will output all the supported browser prefixes, as well as the official syntax - much more than just webkit.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Fixed above.

Comment: What version of compass are you using? If it's 0.12.x, have you installed, and properly imported the compass-animation plugin? If you comment out the `keyframes` mixin, does the `animation` mixin throw an error?

Comment: I believe I use the last one as I installed with the command they provide in the site, I installed it 10 days a go

Comment: Then you need to install an animation plugin as well. I linked to the wrong one initially. You need [compass-animation](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation). You'll need to install the gem, require it in your `config.rb`, and import it in your sass code.

Comment: @EricMeyer I have a fairly simple bit, using Compass 0.13.3.alpha.4, but getting no result (that is, no animation on page load.

`code`
  #sliding-loader-animation-right {
    @include keyframes(bounceInRight);
    @include animation(bounceInRight .1s infinite linear);
  }
`code`

Comment: Your code is creating an empty animation called bounceInRight and then calling it. That won't work. Keyframes should be called at the root level (not nested in an element) and should include a `%` list of keyframes with styles. Then you can apply it to an element with `animation()`. If you want pre-defined animations, you'll also want the "compass-animate" plugin, which comes with `bounceIneRight` keyframes already defined - so you could skip that step.

Comment: this makes so much more sense. I couldn't understand the way it was documented in the compass website.